# Express middleware know if incoming will be a 404

Tags: node.js, express

*(i know there are a few official tools for SSR but we decided to roll our own for various reasons that are not important for this question)*

We have a prototype of a server-side renderer running in nodejs for vue with Puppeteer. It works very well and now I would like to cache routes we want to cache. The cache invalidation is simple.

We intend to use Redis to hold the cache objects.

### Proposed flow of the server:

1. Incoming request hits the express app
2. An express request middleware 1st checks if the route should be cached, if not return index.html. END else continue.
3. The same middleware checks if there is a Redis cache object based on incoming request object data, if yes return cache & END else continue.
4. Express router matches the request to a route, passes the request to the respective domain layer, creates the cache then returns it. END else next.
5. No express route found, handle 404 & END.

### The question I have relates to proposed flow step 2

##### To know if the request should be cached is based on 2 parameters:

1. does the request cookie contain a valid token
2. is the request path one which is also defined in the express routes

The express routes currently look as follows, but is liable to evolve:

- GET /channel/:name
- GET /channel/:name/:tag
- GET /item/:id

So, how in step 2 can we check if the incoming route is a route that would match the express router?

Comment: Express already handle this. Put your middleware in the route after the path but before the endpoint/controller. For example `app.get('/channel/:name', MIDDLEWARE, handleChannelName)`. The middleware itself does not need to (should not IMHO) do the check

Comment: Yes we thought as much but wondered if there was a way to inject this as a global request middleware opposed to injected to each route 1 by 1

Comment: yeah use `app.use`, rtm https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Excellent contribution @LawrenceCherone lol... rtq?

Comment: rtq.. no sorry. I saw your comment asking about global middleware. app.use is what you use for that lol

Comment: Use global middleware for global logic. Use path middleware for path logic

Answer (score 1):

As said in first comment, express already provide a way to do this :

```js
app.get('/channel/:name/:tag', YOUR_MIDDLEWARE, (req, res) => {
    // Your Handler
})
```

Comment: yeap... seems to be the way. I was hoping there might be a more global way